# Proper conjugation of 生む

Tags: conjugations

I am trying to state a goal to produce something, such as:
目的 は 成果 を 生むて います。
Is this the proper conjugation to indicate I plan to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The verb 生{う}む, which means "to birth, or to produce" conjugates as such, when linking to います:

> 目的は成果を**生｛う｝んで**います。

However, be aware that the -ています style of conjugation refers to an action in progress, which may not be what you want to express.

For stating your goal, you could use ことです instead, like so:

> 目的は成果を生む**ことです**。

That being said, this could be a very "simple" way of expressing this. I definitely suggest you look around to see how best to word this kind of phrase in Japanese for a business context, if that's your end goal.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you again @psosuna!